# Pre-Created SQLite database integrate into android app

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am trying to develop a dictionary app via Android Studio and SQLite. Watched huge amount of video tutorials, but in videos i can't find what i want. I have a database with words and their meanings, i want to integrate it in app. May be someone can advice books or their known tutorials.Thx

Tried to copy code in videos and looked for books, they all was little bit unclear and not covered parts that i wanted.

Comment: show what you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Design and Create the database using you favourite SQLite Management tool (e.g. DB Browser for SQLite, Navicat and others).

2) Create an empty App (or an App according to a template empty is simplest).

3) Create an assets folder in the Apps src/main.

4) Create a databases folder in the newly created assets.

5) Copy the database file into the assets/database folder. used.

6) Read and follow the instructions at [SQLiteAssetHelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper/blob/master/README.markdown#database-upgrades), noting that the database name will be the same as the file name including the file extension if